# Wordpress how to remove submenu of the top level admin menu

Tags: wordpress

Like  Main menu is Settings and has sub menus as bellow :

1. General
2. Writing
3. Reading
4. Discussion
5. Media
6. Permalinks

i want to remove Permalinks menu. so how can i do that please help me.

Comment: Do you mean in Admin panel?

Comment: Yes, in wordpress admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function remove_submenus() {
  global $submenu;
  unset($submenu['options-general.php'][40]); // Permalinks
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_submenus');
```